# Can't use minikube docker daemon

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

[eval $(minikube docker-env)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/#reusing-the-docker-daemon) doesn't seams to work for me locally. It runs with no error, but after running the command the `docker` command is not avaliable to be used. I'm using git bash on windows 10 with:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.6", GitCommit:"6260bb08c46c31eea6cb538b34a9ceb3e406689c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-21T06:34:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"", Minor:"", GitVersion:"v1.9.0", GitCommit:"925c127ec6b946659ad0fd596fa959be43f0cc05", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-01-26T19:04:38Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: which error do you get when running docker commands?

Comment: just `bash: docker: command not found`

Comment: You need to have Docker installed

Comment: well.... that is embarrassing but that was the issue, thank you @fiunchinho. I thought I wasn't needed to install docker

Comment: I've wrote an answer with a link to a guide on how to install kubernetes and Docker for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Docker so the docker commands are available. You can follow [this guide on how to install kubernetes and docker on Windows 10](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wasimbloch/2017/01/23/setting-up-kubernetes-on-windows10-laptop-with-minikube/).